# Random line in smooth shading?

Tags: modeling, retopology

Flat shading and even Auto-Smooth Shading works completely fine. It's just Smooth Shading that seems broken. The blueish coloured topology with the broken shading is applied with the following modifiers: Mirror, Subdivision Surface, Shrinkwrap. It is shrinkwrapped to the sculpted model below it (greenish colour). I was working in flat shading and switched over to smooth shading only to find this. I closed and opened the program and that did nothing. There's no overlapping vertices that I can see, it just decided to shade it weird idk. [image: example]

Comment: It looks like you have normals flipped in that area - reset by selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then pressing Shift+N (Recalculate Normals Outside).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.